# LISP; Symbols And Globals

Tags: variables, lisp, global, symbols

I have some problems with my homework. My goal is to create symbols which represent students with name, surename and also their matriculation number (property-list). Also I have use a global variable for all the students I created.

My code looks like this:

```
(defun student-create (firstName lastName matr)
(setq newStudent (gensym "studentNr."))
(setf (get 'newStudent 'firstName ) firstName )
(setf (get 'newStudent 'lastName ) lastName)
(setf (get 'newStudent 'matr ) matr)
;(append  (list newStudent)*stu-liste*)  ;no global list?
)

(student-create 'asdf 'dfgh '132654)
(student-create 'a 'b '123)
(student-create 'c 'd '234)
(student-create 'e 'f '345)
```

So this is the function I want to create students with. I input first and last name and also the matriculation number.

It works for the symbol newStudent but as you can see, the function is not that dynamic. Every time I use the function, newStudent get's overwritten.
 Also I have a problem with saving all the symbols in a global variable.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newStudent` is treated like a global variable in your code, that is why it is overwritten with each invocation of `student-create`. You should use that knowledge to think again about how to store a list (or whatever data structure) of students into a global variable.

What you want instead in `student-create` is a new, local binding for the generated symbol each time the function is invoked. You can use [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm#let) for this purpose.

Actually, this homework looks a lot like [the example for `get` in the CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get.htm)...

Comment: Thank you for your help!